# jquery .click() doesn't work on iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone

I have the following on a website:

```
<div id="info-icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);">info</a></div>
<div id="info-panel" style="display:none;">
    <div id="info-close"></div>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Which is run by the following jquery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#info-icon').on('tap', 'a', function () {
        $('#info-panel').show('slow', function() {
        });
    });

    $("#info-close").click(function () {
        $("#info-panel").hide(1000);
    });
});
```

It works fine in Firefox, Safari, IE and even Android, but fails to work on iphone. I've tried a couple of solutions including changing the .click() for .on ('tap') but nothing seems to work.
What am I missing?

-edit-
Fixed my example code, realised I had missed the a tag in the opening div.

Comment: Did you turn on debug console?

Comment: Mindbreaker - Yes, it doesn't even seem to register the touch as an event. It's like I'm touching a picture with no event tied to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('touchstart click', '#info-icon', function () {
    $('#info-panel').show('slow');
});

$(document).on('touchstart click', '#info-close', function () {
    $("#info-panel").hide(1000);
});
```

Comment: I tried this after seeing it elsewhere; no luck. Does it require the touchstart to be defined somehow?

Comment: Nope, still no response! It's as if it's not even registering the touch event.

Comment: That got it! It worked second try, guess my cache hadn't cleared properly.